# Sencha touch + phonegap. Dataview render on android 4.0

Tags: android, cordova, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I'm stuck with android 4.0.3 problem. When my app is loaded dataview should appear(on the main page). But there is an empty space until I tap this space. After tap everything is ok. The same applies to the list and nested list view. Just load app, then empty screen and after tap - no problem. Everything is ok on iPhone or elder android versions.

Maybe someone's faced with the same problem?

Dataview code(nothing special):

```
  xtype: 'dataview',
  itemTpl: '<div class="judge-list-item"><tpl if="img"><img src="{img}"/></tpl><small>{description}</small><h4>{title}</h4></div>',
  scrollable: false,
  styleHtmlContent: true,
  listeners: {
            initialize: function () {
                           ...
                        },
                        itemtap: function (dataview, indexx, target, record, eOpts) {
                           ...
                        }
             }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Ext.defer(function() {
    myDataview.refresh();
}, 50);
```